# How can two algebraic surfaces be homeomorphic but one is minimal and the other is not?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was perusing a paper by Ruan: "Symplectic Topology on Algebraic 3-Folds." In the paper, he says that there is an algebraic surface called the Barlow surface $B$ which is minimal and homeomorphic to $R_8$, the complex projective plane blown-up at 8 points.

My naive understanding of minimal algebraic surfaces leads me to some confusion. For $B$ to be minimal means that it does not contain any rational curves with self-intersection $-1$. On the other hand, the intersection form of $R_8$ evidently tells us that $R_8$ contains curves with self-intersection $-1$; i.e. the exceptional divisors which are rational. Since the claim is that $B$ and $R_8$ are homeomorphic, then they should have equivalent intersection forms. If so, should $B$ not have $-1$ curves?

I am misunderstanding something but have not been able to figure out what I am misunderstanding. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: In view of complex geometry, a rational curve in a surface is a topological 2-sphere which is at the same time a complex curve. A homeomorphism, say $\phi$, does not need to preserve complex structure, so $\phi$ may sends this 2-sphere to a real 2-dimensional submanifold which is not a complex curve in the new algebraic surface.

Comment: @AGlearner that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: @AGlearner So any homeomorphism between the two will necessarily have to disrupt the complex structure? And therefore, all the homology classes $C \in H_2(B)$ such that $C \cdot C = -1$ do not have a rational curve as a representative.

Comment: In the case you are working on, yes.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, sometimes I think a comment is too short to be an answer, or if I really decide to write an answer, I'll figure out the last detail and elaborate on the writing. However, I don't have time to devote to that. So I think if OP is happy with the hint from the comment, everything will be fine.

Comment: There are pairs of algebraic surfaces which are even *diffeomorphic* with one minimal and the other not. For example, the first and third Hirzebruch surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer consisting of the discussion from the comments in order to mark this question as answered once this is upvoted or accepted.

> In view of complex geometry, a rational curve in a surface is a topological 2-sphere which is at the same time a complex curve. A homeomorphism, say $\phi$, does not need to preserve complex structure, so $\phi$ may sends this 2-sphere to a real 2-dimensional submanifold which is not a complex curve in the new algebraic surface. – [**AG learner**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/243889/ag-learner)